# <ProxyMatch> - Specific URL

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-proxy

I want to only allow `https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify` but not `https://www.google.com/`

`<ProxyMatch "^https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify[^/]+)">`

But it seems to block everything rather than allowing it through.

Is it possible to only whitelist on a very specific URL

Comment: Reverse or Forward proxy?

Answer (score 1):

As you're reverse proxying, you should choose a location in your website where the proxied content should get shown.

Let's say you want only the content in:

```
https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify
```

To be shown at:

```
https://yourwebsite.example.com/google_site_verification
```

In your VirtualHost configuration if you use it, or in the main server config if not you have to enble `mod_ssl` as your upstream (google) is accessed in HTTPS as for your example and putting the proxy directives:

```
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so

SSLProxyEngine On
ProxyPass /google_site_verification https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify
ProxyPassReverse /google_site_verification https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify
```

And you should be ok